# How to generate an HTML JFR report on JMC 8?

Tags: jmc

I hope somebody could help with the following.

In JMC6 to generate a JFR report the syntax was:

```
java com.oracle.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.report.JfrRulesReport file.jfr -format html|json -min ok
```

Then I had to move to JMC8 (http://jdk.java.net/jmc/8/) and started to have issues with the syntax of that report. Based on https://github.com/openjdk/jmc , it should be:

```
java -cp <the built core jars> org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.report.html.JfrHtmlRulesReport <file> [<outputfile>]
```

The output shows no error and a 16K HTML is generated no matter what JFR file is passed as an argument. When viewing that HTML in a browser, it shows nothing but "Show OK Results". I tried with Mozilla, Chrome, and Edge, with similar results.

According to the source code of that html, some images are created, but I found no way to see them.

This Oracle JDK1.8u301 on Win10:

```
$ java -version
  java version "1.8.0_301"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode)
$ echo %CLASSPATH%
plugins\org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules_8.0.1.qualifier.jar;plugins\org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder_8.0.1.qualifier.jar;plugins\org.openjdk.jmc.common_8.0.1.qualifier.jar;plugins\org.lz4.lz4-java_1.7.1.jar;plugins\org.owasp.encoder_1.2.3.jar
```

Has anybody generated a HTML JFR report on JMC8 successfully to provide tips?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

An additional jar file was required to produce the output:

```
org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.jdk_8.1.0.qualifier.jar
```

In the latest version of JMC8.1.0, the list of jar files is:

```
org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules_8.1.0.qualifier.jar;
org.openjdk.jmc.common_8.1.0.qualifier.jar;
org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder_8.1.0.qualifier.jar;
org.lz4.lz4-java_1.7.1.jar;
org.owasp.encoder_1.2.3.jar;
org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.jdk_8.1.0.qualifier.jar
```